# numba not working because of an inconsistency with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba, jit

I have been stuck with this problem since a couple of days ago. I wanted to use numba for a project, so I created a conda environment in python=3.10.4

```
conda create -n scycom
```

Then I install the packages I need from the main repository

```
conda install numpy scipy numba matplotlib jupyter
```

which results in the installation of numpy=1.21.5 and numba=0.55.1

When I am done installing I run jupyter lab `jupyter lab --port=8888` and create a notebook. When I type `from numba import jit`, I get the following error message

```
ImportError: Numba needs NumPy 1.21 or less
```

with a problem apparently arising with `_ensure_critical_deps()`. This is puzzling because numpy is version 1.21.5.

**My attempts to fix this problem**

1. Given that it seemed a compatibility issues, I tried downgrading to numpy=1.20.1 but the problem persists and, sometimes, other compatibility issues with glib show up. In fact, the exact same error message arises
2. I created an environment with python=3.8.13, with numpy=1.20.1 and numba=0.55.1, facing the exact same error messages
3. I tried different combinations of libraries but I could solve this incompatibility
4. I tried a few internet solutions but I did not find that any really fit into my problem

I hope somebody willing to help has faced and solved a similar issue

Comment: check [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148065/numba-needs-numpy-1-20-or-less-for-shapley-import) [2](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7339) [3](https://numba.discourse.group/t/importerror-numba-needs-numpy-1-21-or-less/1225). Now, I have numba 0.55.1 and numpy 1.21.3. If you have problem with them yet, I suggest unistalling numpy and numba, and reinstall them again, preferably install numba at first then numpy if needed.

Comment: Add a flag. In fact, I also met the same error about NumPy version complained from Numba. But I am using the Numba source code to develop sth, rather than a pre-built python package.